# Deduce the type of data in a string

Tags: python, type-conversion

I would like to try to deduce the type of data in a string.

**Scenario:**
I have a CSV file which contains rows of data, and I would like to store this data in a database.
I do not want to store all the fields as strings.
Since the fields in the CSV might change, I cannot assume anything about their types.

**Example (CSV file):**

```
[Row 1 - column names] --> "name", "age" , "children"
[Row 2 - data row    ] --> "John", "45.5", "3"
...
[Row n - data row    ] --> ...
```

In this case, by looking at the data in the rows, I would like to deduce that `name` is a column of strings, `age` is a column of floats and `children` is a column of integers.

**My attempt:**
The simplest approach would be to try conversions, and decide upon the type when a certain conversion succeeds.
I wrote a method for this purpose which looks like this:

```
def deduceType(str):
    try:
        #first try to convert to int:
        int(str)
        return 0 #integer
    except ValueError:
        try:
            #not integer, try float:
            float(str)
            return 1 #float
        except ValueError:
            #not float, so deduct string
            return 2 #string
```

**My question:**
The problem is that if I want to be able to deduce more data types (booleans, longs, unsigned numeric types, etc...), then this approach becomes cumbersome and inaccurate.

Is there a neater, more efficient and rigorous way to do this?

**Answer (edit):**
Based on Martijn Pieters answer, I'm doing this:

```
def deduceType(str):
    try:
        return type(ast.literal_eval(str))
    except ValueError:
        return type('') #string
```

Comment: Why don't you know the type of data that you have in the CSV file? If you know what fields the file will contain, you can have a mapping between field names and data types, eg.: field_type = {'name': str, 'age': int}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) on the value; it'll interpret it as a python literal. If that fails, you have a string instead.

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("45.5")
45.5
>>> ast.literal_eval("3")
3
>>> ast.literal_eval("John")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/ast.py", line 68, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/ast.py", line 67, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

Comment: @Satyajeet: no, `datetime` objects are not considered literals. `literal_eval()` only supports Python literals.

Comment: Hmm...make sense...just read the docs... So Do you think if there's any "magical" method which can deduce all type of datatypes given a string...! I know i can create that method myself(specific to given requirement of course), Just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: @Satyajeet: if you need arbitrary object handling, use the `pickle` module to serialise and deserialise. There is no such magic method for 'source-like' text, sorry.

Comment: @Satyajeet: note that `ast.literal_eval()` is implemented as a walk over an AST parse tree, you can always extend this idea to support specific object types.